# Error in chunk-content-script in Nuxt 3 app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

- Operating System: Windows_NT
- Node Version:     v18.18.2
- Nuxt Version:     3.9.1
- CLI Version:      3.10.0
- Nitro Version:    2.8.1
- Package Manager:  yarn@1.22.21
- Builder:          -
- User Config:      ssr, css, app, modules, i18n, sitemap, image, device, site, nitro, build, security, devServerHandlers, runtimeConfig, vite
- Runtime Modules:  @nuxtjs/tailwindcss@6.11.4, @nuxtjs/i18n@8.0.0, @vueuse/nuxt@10.7.2, @nuxtjs/device@3.1.1, @p
  inia/nuxt@0.4.11, nuxt-simple-robots@4.0.0-rc.13, nuxt-simple-sitemap@4.4.1, nuxt-security@0.14.4, @nuxt/image@1.3.0
- Build Modules:    -

Describe the bug:
I do not know when this error appeared. I want to fix this, but I cannot handle these errors. What is chunk-content-scripts? How handle such kind of errors?

I've tried to handle with the following:

```js
onErrorCaptured((error) => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

And with `error-handler.ts` in `plugins`:

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.config.errorHandler = (error, instance, info) => {
    console.log('~: ', error, instance, info)
  }

  // Also possible
  nuxtApp.hook('vue:error', (error, instance, info) => {
    console.log('~2: ', error, instance, info)
  })
})
```

But none of them fired.

Image of error:

[image]

I also tried to comment out all in the app.vue, but the error still appears in the console

Comment: Might be a browser extension (had a similar issue)

Answer (score 1):

The ModHeader chrome extension disabling fixed this issue for me

Comment: Not sure how this is related to ModHeader, Do you have any configurations in ModHeader?

Comment: Different situation - same JS errors in console. This was the fix. Thank you!